# Beats can’t reach Elastic Service

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, elastic-stack, filebeat

I've been running my ECK (Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes) cluster for a couple of weeks with no issues. However, 3 days ago filebeat stopped being able to connect to my ES service. All pods are up and running (Elastic, Beats and Kibana).

Also, shelling into filebeats pods and connecting to the Elasticsearch service works just fine:

```sh
curl -k  -u "user:$PASSWORD" https://quickstart-es-http.quickstart.svc:9200
```

```json
{
  "name" : "aegis-es-default-4",
  "cluster_name" : "quickstart",
  "cluster_uuid" : "",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.14.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "",
    "build_date" : "",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Yet the filebeats pod logs are producing the below error:

```
ERROR   
[publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:154  
Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://quickstart-es-http.quickstart.svc:9200)): 
Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: could not connect to a compatible version of Elasticsearch: 
503 Service Unavailable: 
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      { "type": "master_not_discovered_exception", "reason": null }
    ],
    "type": "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason": null
  },
  "status": 503
}
```

I haven't made any changes so I think it's a case of authentication or SSL certificates needing updating?

My filebeats config looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
  name: quickstart
  namespace: quickstart
spec:
  type: filebeat
  version: 7.14.0
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: quickstart
  config:
    filebeat:
      modules:
        - module: gcp
          audit:
            enabled: true
            var.project_id: project_id
            var.topic: topic_name
            var.subcription: sub_name
            var.credentials_file: /usr/certs/credentials_file
            var.keep_original_message: false
          vpcflow:
            enabled: true
            var.project_id: project_id
            var.topic: topic_name
            var.subscription_name: sub_name
            var.credentials_file: /usr/certs/credentials_file
          firewall:
            enabled: true
            var.project_id: project_id
            var.topic: topic_name
            var.subscription_name: sub_name
            var.credentials_file: /usr/certs/credentials_file
  daemonSet:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: filebeat
        automountServiceAccountToken: true
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
        hostNetwork: true
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        containers:
        - name: filebeat
          volumeMounts:
          - name: varlogcontainers
            mountPath: /var/log/containers
          - name: varlogpods
            mountPath: /var/log/pods
          - name: varlibdockercontainers
            mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          - name: credentials
            mountPath: /usr/certs
            readOnly: true
        volumes:
        - name: varlogcontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/containers
        - name: varlogpods
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/pods
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: credentials
          secret:
            defaultMode: 420
            items:
            secretName: elastic-service-account
```

And it was working just fine - haven't made any changes to this config to make it lose access.

Comment: What is the output of `curl -XGET 'https://quickstart-es-http.quickstart.svc:9200/_cluster/state?pretty'`? How many nodes do you have for your ES cluster? Have you changed any ES configs recently not related to Filebeats?

Comment: It's almost 100k lines. Most of it is the schema. Do you want the first few hundred? I have 3 nodes. I haven't changed config but I've had resource constraint issues in the past so I included a lifecycle policy that doesn't seem to be taking effect.

Comment: OK do curl -XGET 'https://quickstart-es-http.quickstart.svc:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'

Answer (score 1):

Did a little more digging and found that there weren't enough resources to be able to assign a master node.

Got this when I tried to run GET /_cat/master and it returned the same 503 no master error. I added a new node pool and it started running normally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So I was on track :)